# Is it possible to tell datatool to ignore certain characters when sorting?

Tags: sorting, datatool

I am making a index as a ";" separated csv file. The index is sorted with the datatool package. The column which is sorted contains utf8 encoded names, including apostrophes, eg. "'Tis" and "ev'ry". The apostrophe is sorted before the letters, but I would like "'Tis" and "ev'ry" to be treated as "Tis" and "evry" in the sorting process.

I have looked in the datatool documentation, but can't seem to find a description of this feature.

Is it possible to achieve the selective sorting with datatool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by putting `\dtlcompareskipcstrue` in the preamble after loading the datatool package and using `\textquoteright` for the apostrophe. The command is ignored in the sorting process, and "'Tis" is sorted as "Tis".